# Binarize an Array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an column vector that signifies the day of the week

```
[1,2,2,3,4]
```

I need to binarise this vector in the sense that every item in the original vector must be transformed to a vector where the number indicates an index that needs to be 1 and the rest must be 0.

```
[[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What are your ideas? Also, is 8 the maximum number possible or is this arbitrary?

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: What defines the lenghts of the transformed arrays, in your example 9?

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar The days of the week is between [1-7]  so basically I just have to add a column on either end so not to get an out of bounds error

Comment: @JavaBeginner Why are you worried about an "out of bounds error"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do it by composing your binary list with zeroes except in the given position in a list comprehension which gives a nice one-liner:

```
w=[1,2,2,3,4]
m = [[0]*(pos)+[1]+[0]*(9-pos-1) for pos in w]
```

result:

```
m = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension would be:

```
>> vector = [1,2,2,3,4]       
>> [[int(i==j) for i in range(10)] for j in vector]
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: That's a nice answer, but depends on Boolean values `True` and `False` often being identical to `1` and `0`. That makes it a bit less simple.

Comment: @RoryDaulton The int values of `True` and `False` being 1 and 0 is [defined behaviour](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/), in fact `bool` in python is a subclass of int, True and False are the same as 1 and 0. Of course it would also be possible to use `1 if i==j else 0`, but that is much less readable imho.

Comment: All that is true, which is why I wrote "a bit less simple" rather than "less readable." My comment was not a criticism, just a note, and the only upvote on your answer so far is mine--this I clearly do not disapprove of your answer.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I did not take it as dissapprovement but as an incentive to clarify on the used form and why it works this way in python, possibly for other readers of these comments too